# UWP: Visual Studio doesn't see all the installed SDKs

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, uwp, windows-10

I am not sure what happened, but after an update I don't see all the SDK versions in Visual Studio anymore, only one of them:

[image]

Visual studio installer says that the SDKs are installed:
[image]

But Visual studio says and update is required:
[image]

And this is what I see in Control Panel:
[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You could try repairing or reinstalling Visual Studio..

Comment: how did you get into this state? I mean what did you do last before noticing you are in this state.